# Edit a 2D array through a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have this function :
    void foo( char tab[8][8] )

I want this function to edit the values of the tab array, so i tried theses syntax :

```
void foo( char *(*tab)[8][8] )
void foo( char *(tab)[8][8] )
void foo( char **tab )
```

And a LOT of others. I always get a fail while compiling, like this one :
    error: cannot convert 'char (*)[8][8]' to 'char* (*)[8][8]' for argument '1' (...)

So, my quesiton is : how to create and pass to a function a pointer to a 2D array ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the function call.

Comment: At this momment, it looks like foo( point ); where point is :         char (*point)[8][8] = &originalVar;

Comment: Is `originalVar` a 2D array?

Comment: Try "char *". A "two-dimensional" array of characters is simply a sequence of characters. Though, it might be a good idea to pass array dimensions to your function...

Comment: originalVar is a 2D array, declared as follow : char originalVar[8][8] = {'a', 'a', (...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This time try to declare your function as

```
void foo( char (*tab)[8] );
```

and call it as

```
foo(point);
```

Note that in this case you need to pass only array name as it decays to pointer when passed to a function (some exceptions are there). After decay it is of type `char (*)[8]`.

You can do it also by declaring

```
void foo( char (*tab)[8][8] );
```

and call it as

```
foo(&point);
```

In this case notice that I passed `&poinnt`, i.e, address of the entire array which is of type `char (*)[8][8]`.
Sample:

```
void foo(char (*tab)[8][8])
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 68j++)
        {
              scanf("%d", &(*tab)[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error, error: cannot convert 'char (*)[8][8]' to 'char (*)[8]' for argument '1' to 'void foo(char (*)[8](...)

Comment: @Rogue No. Apparently, you didn't pay attention to the "and call it as" part of this answer.

Comment: `point` is of type `char (*)[8]` (after decay). You should not get any error.

Comment: @haccks `s/is/decays into`

Comment: @H2CO3; OK. Did that.

Comment: @H2CO3; Added that in answer too.

Answer (score 1):

With an array, you can always modify the data in the function because what is passed is a pointer (in the absence of `const` qualifiers, of course).  That is, you could write:

```
void foo(char tab[8][8])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            tab[i][j] = (x + y) % 2 : 'X' : 'O';
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
void calling_func(void)
{
    char board[8][8];
    foo(board);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            putchar(tab[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

---

You can get the error messages you were seeing if you write:

```
   foo(&board);
```

That passes a pointer to an array to the function.  For that to work, you have to rewrite the function as:

```
void foo(char (*tab)[8][8])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            (*tab)[i][j] = (x + y) % 2 : 'X' : 'O';
    }
}
```

However, this is seldom the correct way to write the code.  Use the first alternative until this is forced upon you (which probably won't be this year — I don't recall having to use a pointer to an array except to answer questions on SO, but maybe it was such a ghastly experience that I have forgotten all about it).

Comment: @Rogue Note that the first part of this answer is essentially the same as haccks' answer (because in a function declaration, `char tab[8][8]` is equivalent with `char (*tab)[8]`), which you claimed not to work...

Comment: Yes, i noticed this after, i've edit my comments to match this.